# OpenCV Gender Classification using CascadeClasifier vs. FaceRecognizer (FisherFace)

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to find the best way to go about gender detection. I'm using opencv, and currently everything is fine except the gender accuracy is not very good, even though i have 1500 sample images for each male and female.

I'm using the default lbp face cascade file to detect faces, then a custom compiled fisherface recognizer model to classify the face as male or female.

I was wondering if anybody had any thoughts about generating an lbp cascade for each male and female faces, where negative samples would contain the opposite gender? Before i try it myself, i wanted to know if anybody knew whether this would be a waste of time

Can I use the cascadeclassifier in opencv once to check for males in the frame, and a second time to check for females?

EDIT:
Here are the steps i'm taking to figure out of a male or female is in front of the camera:

1. Detect the face
2. crop the face
3. detect at least two eyes in the top half of the cropped image (temp image used)
4. detect left and right eyes
5. rotate cropped image around left eye to align eyes
6. translate image so center between eyes is center of cropped image and eye's are vertically in "common" with sample image's eyes
7. resize image to 150x150 keeping aspect ratio
8. normalize image for lighting
9. classify face as male or female using fisherfaces

Comment: If you don't get any hits, you might have better luck on the [Signal Processing exchange](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: oh yeah thanks, i guess i wasn't for sure where to put this because its not technically a programming question, but it's done in programming

Comment: imho the way should be to first detect faces and second for any face to classify whether it's male or female, because intra-differences between male and female faces are much smaller than intra-differences between faces and background! so it should be easier for the algorithm to decide between male/female once you are sure that is a face at all. but not sure whether lbp, hog or haar is suitable to classify between gender.

Comment: thanks micka, you make a good point, just thought it might be something to look into but i don't think i'll waste the time

Comment: just wondering what could have made this a better question? it looks like some people don't think it was a very good question. it would be nice if there was a comment popup next to the reputation that would explain up or down votes, at least downvotes anyway so people would know in the future how to better ask a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you create a gender specific lbp cascade for detection, that will be a waste of time. That type of detection uses "haar-like" features, which are basically lines. Both male and female faces have the same features in that respect so your detector's negative and positive images will be identical mathematically.

There are many reasons why the fisherface discriminant for gender recognition is "crap" as you say, could be due to several reasons. What type of preprocessing are you doing on the faces once they are detected? Are you aligning the faces? If not, you don't have a chance. Are you normalizaing for lighting? Are you using the ASM to find feature points of the faces and morph out of plane rotations to frontal views? Preprocessing is everything when it comes to any type of image processing.

Comment: I've updated my question to include exactly what i'm currently doing. i'll mark your answer as correct as it does actually answer my question about whether its a waste of time or not to try using an lbp cascade classifier, but if you have any other suggestions on the process i'm using to get better results, that'd be cool!

Comment: Why not resize it so the distance between the eyes is the same? Resizing the image to 150x150 in no way guarantees the faces are the same size.

Comment: of course! thats a great idea! thank you, i'll try it out

Comment: could you explain a little more about "Are you using the ASM to find feature points of the faces and morph out of plane rotations to frontal views?" or point me in a direction to understand more about that? unless the facerecognizer does that automatically, my process does not include that